# UISwipeGestureRecognizer works in wrong direction

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I add 4 UISwipeGestureRecognizer to image view.but when I swipe right,up UISwipeGestureRecognizer is triggered.When I swipe left,no UISwipeGestureRecognizer is triggered.When I swipe up,left UISwipeGestureRecognizer is triggered.When I swipe down,down UISwipeGestureRecognizer is triggered.
Here is my code

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //imageView is an outlet of image view
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightAction)];
    swipeRight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftAction)];
    swipeLeft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeUpAction)];
    swipeLeft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDown=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDownAction)];
    swipeDown.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];
}

- (void)swipeRightAction
{
    NSLog(@"swipe right");

}

- (void)swipeLeftAction
{
    NSLog(@"swipe left");

}

-(void)swipeUpAction
{

    NSLog(@"swipe up ");
}

-(void)swipeDownAction
{

    NSLog(@"swipe down ");
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) ||
        (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft))
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeUpAction)];
// HERE
swipeLeft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];
```

It should be swipeUp instead of swipeLeft.